# Issue with printing the correct size of a string in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, undefined-behavior

In the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char word[]="";
    scanf("%s",word);

    printf("%s: %d\n", word, sizeof(word));
}
```

```
Input: 
Hello

Output: 
Hello: 1
```

Why **`sizeof(word)`** prints the original size of **`word`** although it contains "Hello" after executing **`scanf()`** function instead of empty string.

I expect the output to be **`Hello: 6`**.
I understand that the issue is related to the way I am initializing the **`word`** array, but as you can see I want to avoid setting a static size to **`word`** and any string related **`header file`**.

I'm using VS Code and gcc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0 compiler

Comment: Your buffer has only **one byte**. Try `char word[100] = ""; scanf("%99s", word);` In C, a buffer does not get automatically resized - you have to allow enough size yourself.

Comment: Answering your question with a question: How much memory was allocated to `word`?  Therein lie your answer.  Following on, this evokes UB as `scanf` has written to ‘unknown’ (unallocated) memory; therefore *any* output should be untrusted.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the array, not the length of the string. To get the length of a null-terminated string use `strlen`.

Comment: As for your array, in C arrays have a fixed size. Once set it can't change. There are no dynamic arrays in C. This should really have been mentioned in your class, beginners book or tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not dynamically change the size of an array when you use `scanf`.

`char word[]="";` declares an array that is large enough to contain the array indicated by the string literal `""`.

`""` means a string of zero characters terminate by a null byte. This string is represented by just one byte, the null byte. So an array for it contains one element.

`scanf("%s",word);` asks `scanf` to read a string from the standard input stream and to write it to the array `word`. If there is are any non-white-space characters in the input, this will attempt to write beyond the end of the single-byte array `word`. Then the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

If the program does continue, `sizeof(word)` is the size of the array as it was defined, one byte. It is not the length of the string that `scanf` scans.

To read a string, you can start by defining `word` to be a large array, such as `char word[1024]`. This is tolerable for a starting exercise, but you will learn better techniques for handling any input later.

Then, to find the length of the string that is currently in the array, using `strlen`, declared in the `<string.h>` header. `sizeof` gives the size of an object, which is the number of bytes reserved for it in memory. `strlen` gives the length of the string defined by the values currently in the object. By analogy, `sizeof` gives the size of a box, and `strlen` says how much is in the box at the moment.